# STL VS13 C++: Error C4996 not disabling

Tags: c++, stl

I have this code in VS13:

```
double distance(vector <double> point) {
    return sqrt(inner_product(point[0], point[4], point, 0));
}

int main() {
    vector < double > point {2, 2, 2, 2};
    cout << distance(point);
    cin.get();
}
```

which invokes

```
    error C4996 ('std::_Inner_product2': Function call with parameters that may be unsafe - this call relies on the caller to check that the passed values are correct. To disable this warning, use -D_SCL_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS)
 c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\xutility(372): error C2825: '_Iter': must be a class or namespace when followed by '::'
    c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\xutility(372): error C2039: 'value_type' : is not a member of '`global namespace''
    c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\xutility(372): error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'value_type'
    c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\xutility(372): error C2602: 'std::iterator_traits<_InIt>::value_type' is not a member of a base class of 'std::iterator_traits<_InIt>'
```

I know there are many similar questions like this here. I also read a documentation on MSDN.

As a result, I tried next solutions:

1) `#define _SCL_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS`

From past reviews it seemed to work but for me it causes a whole bunch of errors like:

```
c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\xutility(371): error C2825: '_Iter': must be a class or namespace when followed by '::'
```

2)

```
#pragma warning(disable:4996)
#pragma warning(default:4996)
```

Caused the same errors;

3) project properties -> Configuration Properties -> C/C++ -> General -> SDL checks -> No.

Just does not work.

Could you take a look and write how I can disable that error? Thanks!

Comment: `point[4]` is not only outside the vector, but quite simply completely wrong on all counts  - I suggest you read what [`std::inner_product`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/inner_product) expects from its arguments.... Also: Always give a [working example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) - your code won't come even close to compiling with your error, since it breaks long before that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you mean the following function

```
double distance( const std::vector<double> &point ) 
{
    return std::sqrt( std::inner_product( point.begin(), point.end(), point.begin(), 0.0 ) );
}
```

Here is a demonstrative program

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <numeric>
#include <cmath>

double distance( const std::vector<double> &point ) 
{
    return std::sqrt( std::inner_product( point.begin(), point.end(), point.begin(), 0.0 ) );
}

int main()
{ 
    std::vector<double> point = { 2, 2, 2, 2 };

    std::cout << distance( point ) << std::endl;
}
```

The output is

```
4
```

Answer (score 1):

Tools
Options
Advanced

There is a section there for warnings to suppress.
  If I recall correctly 4820;4996;4710 are three I always suppress.